# How do I drive a MOSFET when I have an 11.1v power-supply and an arduino

Tags: arduino, mosfet

I am trying to use a irlb3034 as a switch to power an airsoft motor and control it with an arduino. I am using a diode between the source and the drain and a 2.2k resistor between the gate and the source. Do you have any idea how I can control the mosfet with the arduino? Many thanks,
Thomas

Comment: Do you just want to turn the motor on and off, or control its speed?  In your prior post you put up a schematic -- it would be helpful if you made a schematic that calls out the Arduino, the battery input, the motor and MOSFET, and has a box (I would label it "magic") that goes between the Arduino output and the gate.

Comment: I simply want to turn it on and off. It would be helpful if I could also reverse the direction but I don’t think that’s possible with the currently components. Thanks

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Nope -- that was about whether you could make 12V from 5 with a linear regulator.  This is about how to actually make the motor turn.

Comment: They are duplicates, but the other question is a purely confused one and should be closed as a duplicate of this.  Had the original question not received answers it would have been better to edit this text into it than to repost.

Comment: If it hadn’t been answered, I probably would have added more information to my answer to make it more similar to this one. It was answered and Tim answered the confusing question I asked as best as was possible and I didn’t think starting a whole new question in the comments and edits of that one was a good idea. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Really simple -- get an ESC that's compatible with the motor.  I don't know if an "airsoft motor" is a DC brushed motor or a DC brushless -- count the leads.  If it's got two, then you need an ESC for a brushed motor; if it's got three, then you need an ESC for a brushless motor.  All you need then is a servo output from the Arduino, and that's built into their code base.
- Complicated-er (for your) and less capable: switch the MOSFET gate voltage with a transistor.  Note that, as drawn, the signal from the Arduino means "off", so the motor will go on with battery power until the Arduino comes up.  You'll need another 2N3904 stage for the thing to be off when there's no Arduino.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fntold.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I want this whole thing as a pcb with an atmega328p-au in it so unfortunatly the esc is not an option. I have lots of experience with RC electronics so know how to use that kind of technology. For the mosfet circuit, will it handle 200 amps and 7.4-14v okay? Thanks

Comment: You'll need to work on the 200A part.  Expect smoke until you get it figured out.  200A it 7-14V is not the most economical way to handle 1400-2800W -- are you sure you want to use such a low voltage?

Comment: Unfortunately the motor is capped at 14v and motors for this are very specialist :/. I’ll have a look round for mosfet that will do the trick. I don’t entirely know how this schematic works so I might need to send a few mosfet options and get the thumbs up/down if that’s alright with you

Comment: This is a dangerous way to drive a propeller (if that's what it is). If you reset the ATMega328 or during power on the motor will turn until the software initializes. In addition the IRF530 is only capable of 10-15A so not appropriate for the application.

Comment: Maybe something like the uk.farnell.com/infineon/irl3713pbf/mosfet-n-30v-200a-to-220/dp/… maybe? Also, would it be possible to AnalogWrite instead to stop the problem of the digital pins being set to input by default? Thanks EDIT: Also, for the high current could I use a 5KP18A 5kw diode? Thanks – Vosem Media 8 mins ago

Comment: Could you post a link to the motor in your question?  200A continuous at 12-ish volts is just not a done thing.  Even car starter motors don't run continuously.  Adding the 200A requirement is a considerable game changer.

Comment: The biggest problem here is that using a 'simple' configuration like this the motor will run for about 2 seconds whenever you apply power (unitl the Arduino is initialized). This is dangerous.

Comment: The specs for the irl3713pbf are exceedingly optimistic (in fact, if you look at their "absolute maximum ratings" table you'll see that it's only good for over 200A if the case temperature is maintained at 25C -- so that specification is practically meaningless).  There is a lot of care and feeding involved in getting rated specifications out of a power device, not least of which is turning it on and off fast enough -- which I did not address, because you did not mention the 200A part.

Comment: Sure, and because of the problem of the motor turning on for a few seconds on start, I am going with the circuit Jack Creast supplied on the other post: https://i.stack.imgur.com/36LFD.png
Here is a link to the motor: https://www.bullseyecountrysport.co.uk/shs-high-torque-motor-long-shaft-6144-p.asp It is for a friend into airsoft. It is a high torque SHS motor if you wanted to know
EDIT: Sorry for not mentioning the specifications of the motor